# issue connecting from sql developer to OracleVM virtualbox over port 1521

Tags: linux, oracle

Hello I have used https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/oracle-db-12cr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-6-and-7 to create a oracle DB in oracle virtualbox and I am trying to connect to it using sql developer on the same desktop. I have disabled the firewall already. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0.1/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_CDB1 =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol7-122.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))


CDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol7-122.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = cdb1)
    )
  )

[oracle@ol7-122 bin]$ cat /u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0.1/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora 
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0.1/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol7-122.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Listener Status

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 20-APR-2021 11:15:43

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ol7-122.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                19-APR-2021 13:17:15
Uptime                    0 days 21 hr. 58 min. 27 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0.1/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ol7-122/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ol7-122.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=ol7-122.localdomain)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/u01/app/oracle/admin/cdb1/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "bfcef1c73c025a39e0536a38a8c0e70d" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb1XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

netstat of port 1521 in oracle VM

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.56.106:27356    192.168.56.106:1521     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::1521                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 192.168.56.106:1521     192.168.56.106:27356    ESTABLISHED
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51182    /var/tmp/.oracle/sEXTPROC1521
```

telnet from windows to oracle VM over port 1521

```
Connecting To 192.168.56.106...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1521: Connect failed
```

Comment: How did you configure your VM's network adapter? If you virtualbox VM is configured to use NAT or Nat Network, then you need to configure Port Forwarding from your host machine to VM

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - as an alternative - and I think better -- I've built scores of VBox machines, and I always build and treat them exactly like I would a production server that is located behind a locked door in a lights-out data center.  That is, I _always_ configure either a bridged or a hostonly adapter, and configure it with a fixed IP address in the same subnet as the host machine.  It is the address of that adapter that is referenced in both the listener.ora and any tnsnames.ora

Comment: @EdStevens yeah, agree, it's a good option for more or less persistent networks, but, for example, I use it on my work laptop, ie a lot of different WiFi networks, 7 different VPN clients(some of them even conflict with virtual network adapters), and I use also VMware and hyperv - in such situation Nat network is more preferrable for me

Comment: I have it setup with a vbox host-only adapter setup currently.